# Xamerin Android ListView is not populating when setting Adapter in a callback method

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, xamarin

am trying to populating `ListView` by loading data using a `Web Service`.
And i set code for setting ListView `Adapter` in the `CallBack Method`. But Adapter `GetView Override method` is not firing in this case & ListView is not populating.

But it works when i set adapter in OnCreate(Bundle bundle) Method with dummy data.
Anybody know what i missed ? Do i need call any UI Update method here?

```
  protected List<Product> Products { get; set; }

  protected void FillProductListCallBack(List<Product> products)
   {
      if (products.Any())
      {
        Products = products;
        ProductListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstList);
        ProductListView.Adapter = new ProductScreenAdapter(this, Products);
        ProductListView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback probably returns off the UI thread, which causes your problem. Try doing this instead:

```
protected List<Product> Products { get; set; }

protected void FillProductListCallBack(List<Product> products)
{
    if (products.Any())
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() => 
        {
            Products = products;
            ProductListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstList);
            ProductListView.Adapter = new ProductScreenAdapter(this, Products);
            ProductListView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
        });
    }
}
```